# Correlation between date, time, categorical and numeric variables

Tags: python, r

I have a very large dataset with variables of all types: date, time, categorical and numerical variables. It is a dataset that refers to employment records. And I would like to know if there are correlated variables between them. I know that to make a normal correlation matrix I should only have normalised numeric variables, but this is not the case. Any alternative?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

The only way is to take an individual approach to correlation analysis. Time variables may be treated as continuous variables (at least after some transformation). So it should be possible to use **Pearson Product-Moment Correlation**. For categorial data it should be differentiated between **nominal** and **ordinal** data, where ordinal data exhibits some kind of rank. Here, **Spearman's Rank-Order Correlation** or **Kendall Rank Correlation** may be applied, for which the data has to be *at least* ordinal. Nominal data should be analysed via contingency tables and the likes and maybe some more advanced correlation measures like **Tetrachoric Correlation** to actually get some sort of correlation coefficient [...].

I would get familiar with different correlation methods, their use cases and alternatives.

Comment: Thank you @OliverHennhoefer ! And what are the transformations I should do in order to use Person Product-Moment Correlation?

Comment: You mentioned date and time variables. So with "transformation" I simply meant that you could either turn them into categorial (ordinal) variables (weekday, month, years...) or to turn them into continuous variables like seconds in order to analyze them. Actual data transformation in the sense of a log-transformation or the likes is not strictly required and may be helpful or harmful (in case it destroys the initial linear relationship that is tries to quantify). It depends on your data.